# Best method of many to many database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, entity-relationship

I am currently working on an app for sporting clubs, this allows club admins to manage the divisions, teams, and ultimately the players.

At present I have my database/relationships as follows

```
class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :clubs
  has_many :teams
  attr_accessible :club_id


class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sport
  has_many  :teams
  has_many :users
  has_many  :divisions
  attr_accessible :sport_id

class Division < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  belongs_to  :club
  attr_accessible :club_id

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :users
  has_many  :schedules
  belongs_to :division
  belongs_to :club
  attr_accessible :division_id, :club_id

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :club
  belongs_to :team
  attr_accessiable :club_id, :sport_id
```

essential what I would like is a more concise way of managing this. i.e.

- User can only belong to 1 club, within 1 division, but can have multiple teams
- Team can only belong to 1 division, within 1 club, within 1 sport, but have multiple users
- Division can only belong to 1 club, within 1 sport, but have multiple teams
- Club can only belong to 1 sport, but have multiple teams, and multiple divisions

At present the above is working, but i dont think the relationships/structure is at its best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have singular sport clubs in your country? Here in Germany different divisions of a club can have different sports (my own club e.g. is in Athletics, Cycling, Volleyball, Basketball, Tabletennis and Swimming). In most of my apps I just skip the sport and the divisions: The sport is given from the app's context, and I view club and division as identical. My Athletic-apps just deal with the club, not with the club's division. I view this sacrifice as necessary, as the complexity otherwise overwhelms me – your mileage may vary, of course :-)

Moreover: A user only temporarily belongs to a club, so I have an intermediate relationsship between users and the teams; "Startberechtigung" in german, something like "license" in english I 'ld say; it belongs_to team and belongs_to user and has "start_date" and "stop_date" as additional attributes. That way I even have histories for clubs and users. Important for record lists (again: Athletics)!

After that I would throw away the superfluous transitive relationsships: A user belongs to a team which in turn belongs to the club => use has_many :through's more; you dont need the user belongs_to club.

Now your models should be a bit cleaner.

**Update**:

Dont use classname "User" for the players, this will ultimately lead to a conflict with your user/admins-model. "Player" or "Athlete" is just fine for me.

**Update 2**:

You dont need the :through in each and every case, of course. A scope with includes or a class method might be preferable for you, esp. if you want to bridge over more than one intermediate class.

How about something like (please fill the holes from the recommended guide):

```
class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :clubs
has_many :teams, :through => :clubs, :readonly => false


class Club < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :sport
has_many :teams


class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :club

has_many :athlete_teams
has_many :athletes, :through => :athlete_teams, :readonly => false


class AthleteTeam < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :teams
belongs_to :athletes


class Athlet < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :athlete_teams
has_many :athletes, :through :athlete_teams, :readonly => false
```

Comment: thanks for the advice atastor, what im trying to achieve is that the sports, clubs, teams and players all tie into each other, ie i can see how many clubs within a sport, etc.. what i have been reading about the :throughs i was trying to work out if i can do was Sport `has_many :teams, :through => :clubs` though im not completely over it

Comment: The number 1 source for all kinds of associations is http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html :-) You should really find everything you need there about :throughs!

Comment: is this setup using :through the same as HABTM ?

Comment: As long as you do not add any attributes to the AthleteTeam class, yes ; besides the fact, that with habtm the intermediate table is not ActiveRecord-based.

Answer (score 0):

Help about ActiveRecord Associations can be found on [http://api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

hopefully, this will help you.

Comment: have read this, but still a bit confused on how to achieve the best relationship